# Optimising code to make execution quicker

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Problem Statement : - 
The problem i encountered was in coding competition it was that queryIndex is given in array . An Array Is Given . we have to use the queryIndexArray to get each index and do the following thing in the main array :-**

```
    for k = queryIndex[i] + 1 to array.length 
         if (array[k] < array[queryIndex[i]]){
            array[queryIndex[i]] = 0  
          }
```

I have written the javascript code but the problem is that it takes 10 seconds to run 10.03 seconds to be precise how can i bring it down the runtime to  2 seconds as the problem is time based

**Approach That i Used :-**

```
let arrayLength = 5 ;
let array = [4,3,4,2,1]
let queryIndex = [3,2]
let queryIndexLength = 2

for (let i =0 ; i <queryIndexLength ; i ++ ){
  let forwardIndex = queryIndex[i] + 1
   for (let j = forwardIndex ; j< arrayLength ; j++){
     if (array[forwardIndex] < array[j]  ){
        array[j] = 0 
      }
   }
}
```

This code passes the test cases but problem is it takes 10 seconds to execute and the run time for that problem is 2 seconds only . Should i use some other data structure like sets ? as array is taking much longer time so please suggest the solution ?

Code Brief Description : -

1. it takes value from query index .(first loop is run on query index)
2. increment the value of the queryindex value from 1
3. 2nd inner loop run from queryIndex+1 to array.length
4. Inside it checks the value if array[queryIndex+1] < array[j] (in loop)
   and if the condition is true it updates the value of array[j] =  0

**This just en example code the original test cases values were large enough for array and queryIndex so it was taking 10.03 seconds**

**Problem In approach : - Time complexity it takes 10 seconds on large input i want to get it under 2 seconds so how to Achieve it as its o(n)^2 solution .**

Comment: no clue what the code is doing

Comment: @epascarello The code is taking the index in queryindex for example in this it takes 2 . Increment the index by +1 so it equals to 3. Run the inner loop from  3 to 5 and check the condition in the inner loop and if it matches it run the inner if one code

Comment: @epascarello Added a brief description in the original question also please check. Thanx

Comment: You translated each line of code literally, but we know JavaScript already. What problem does it solve?

Comment: @Ry- I was solving the problem in some coding competition but failed as the code takes 10 sec and they need runtime under 2 sec . So wanted  to know how to optimise this code ?.

Comment: I'd suggest to update your question to explain what the problem is. Then a description of what your solution/approach is, and finally the expected output.  Other than that, this seems a time complexity problem, and from a first sigh your algorithm is a O(n^2) which is definitely the problem. But let's not get ahead ourselves, go on and update the question

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Updated The Question Please Check . Thanx for telling

Comment: Can you include the full statement of the problem? In the above, you use a variable j which is not defined. Also, perhaps you can short-circuit the loop based on the properties of array or queryIndex.

Comment: @mankowitz Sorry . Updated The problem . can you please elaborate  the short-circuit  method . The statement of the problem is not available on the site as it was a coding competition so

Comment: That "*do the following thing in the main array*" code does use the reverse condition. Not that it should matter for the runtime, but still.

Comment: @Bergi can using any other data structure instead of array speed the things up ?.

Comment: @CoffeeMaster No, all you need is arrays :-) See my answer.

Comment: Why down voting the question ?

Comment: @CoffeeMaster Your updated question doesn't explain what the problem is. You just described what's already in code but with words. I need to understand what the problem statement is in order to see what is your code doing

Comment: The downvotes are because your question is not clear, so we can't really help. Please update the question with a clear problem statement.  For example:  "Given an array of N items, we want an output of an array with each item multiplied by 2". This is a clear problem statement, it mentions nothing about code or variables. Just a clear statement of what we need to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in `O(array.length + queryIndex.length*log(queryIndex.length))` with the following algorithm:

```
sort(queryIndex)
minQuery = Infinity
foreach i in queryIndex:
  minQuery = minimum(array[queryIndex[i]], minQuery)
  foreach j of (queryIndex[i] .. queryIndex[i+1]):
    if array[j] > minQuery
      array[j] = 0
```

No need to run over some parts of the big array (from each queryIndex to the end of the array) multiple times, to compare each element against the value at the queryIndex: the condition and action looks the same every time. You only need to find the condition that will match all elements that would have been matched in multiple runs.

Comment: Can you provide some pseudo code as from above statement its hard to interpret the algorithm

Comment: @CoffeeMaster What part is hard to understand?

Comment: @CoffeeMaster Do you understand the idea that I described in the last paragraph though?

Comment: @CoffeeMaster I hope my updated answer is clear enough for you to translate it to JS

Comment: @Bergi I think the above algorithm is not clearly understandable. as 3 step point one don't clearly clarify the point.

Comment: @Amey What part of step 3 do you not understand clearly? Where do feel is ambiguity left when it comes to writing code?

Comment: @Amey When I wrote "*array*", I was always referring to the main array of values. The array of query indices is only indirectly referred to in the instruction "*For each queryIndex*", and directly in "*Sort the queryIndices*".

Comment: @Bergi  1. sorted the query Index [2,3]  2. set min query = infinite   3 step what should I do now ? set min query  to minimum of array value at query index what does the statement means ?  what this statement means set min query to which value ?

Comment: @Amey The `minQuery` should always contain the minimum of the array values encountered so far. So `minQuery = min(array[queryIndex], minQuery)`.

Comment: @Bergi    so for loop of j (  minQuery = min(array[queryIndex],minQuery) , if (array[j]) > minquery than set to zero   ) till query index.length                                               is this correct representation of your algorithm ?

Comment: @Amey Yes. I guess next time I'll rather write pseudocode in the first place :-)

Comment: @Bergi Thanx for correcting so much .Respect  to you for helping

Comment: @Amey I guess you missed the inner loop